# Linked List Prints NULL - C++

Tags: c++, printing, linked-list

So, I am working on this linked list assignment and would really appreciate some help on printing out the elements of the linked list.
So far I have used an array to define the values of the linked list but whenever I try to print the head value using a separate print function, it always comes out NULL. Now I am thinking it might have something to do with some global vs local issues but am unsure. If it is scope problems then some advice on how to globally define the linked list values would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code with my print function and my build function. All I am trying to accomplish right now is printing out the head value defined in the build function from the print function. The head value seems to be consistent through the build function but as soon as I execute the print function it becomes NULL.
Any ideas?

```
void CommunicationNetwork::buildNetwork(){
    std::string a[10] = {"Los Angeles","Phoenix", "Denver", "Dallas","St. Louis", "Chicago", "Atlanta", "Washington, D.C.", "New York", "Boston"};
    City *head = new City;
    head ->cityName=a[0];
    head ->next = NULL;

    City *current = head;
    int i =1;
    while(i<10){

        City *tmp = new City;

        tmp ->cityName = a[i];
        tmp ->next = NULL;
        current ->next = tmp;
        current = current->next;
        i++;
    }

    City *tail = current;
    City *tmp2 = new City;
    tmp2 = head;
    current = tmp2;
    //cout<<"head = "<<head->cityName<<endl;

    while(current != NULL){
        cout<<current->cityName<<" -> ";
        current = current->next;
    }
    if(current == NULL){
        cout<<"NULL"<<endl;
    }
    cout<<head->cityName<<endl;
}
void CommunicationNetwork::printNetwork(){
    cout<<"===Current Path==="<<endl;
    cout<<head->cityName<<endl;
    cout<<"=================="<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You should place spaces around your operators, e.g. `"cout << current->cityName << " -> ";`

Comment: When you used the debugger, and stepped through each statement, which statement is causing the issue?

Comment: Everything runs but my printNetwork() function prints NULL when it should output "Los Angeles"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rusty crystal ball says that your class has a member named `head`. However you are not touching this member in `CommunicationNetwork::buildNetwork`. Instead, you create a brand new local variable

```
City *head = new City;
```

use it throughout the function, and abandon it at the end of thge function. In order to use your class member, replace the above with

```
head = new City;
```

If your class has a member named `tail`, this applies to it as well.

While we're at it, in this fragment

```
City *tmp2 = new City;
tmp2 = head;
```

you allocate a `City` object and immediately forget about it, creating a memory leak.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I spaced that! Thank you so much. I guess I just kept looking past the fact that the head was being defined in my function. Thanks a lot.